# r randomforest caret - seeing predictions

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

I have code as below. I would like to see the actual predictions.

How could I do that? i tried `results`,`fit`,`finalModel`. But i couldnt see actual predictions. My real problem has lot more predictors and I dont get any warnings when I build a model using below method.

```
yy=xx*10+runif(100)
xx=runif(100)
df=data.frame(xx,yy)
library(caret)
randomForestFit <- train(yy ~ ., method = "rf", data =df )
randomForestFit
randomForestFit$results
```

### update1

1. randomForestFit$finalModel$mse and randomForestFit$finalModel$rsq return 500 values? i was expecting to see 100 values...
2. Does randomForestFit$results return rsquared and rmse for the training data? rsquared and rmse are very low. Are they correct? I was expecting to see better results as yy are 10 times xx + some random error

Comment: The predictions are in `randomForestFit$finalModel$predicted`

Comment: thanks...when i do `randomForestFit$finalModel$mse` and `randomForestFit$finalModel$rsq` why do i get 500 values?

Comment: does `randomForestFit$results` return rsquared and rmse for the training data?

Comment: @user2543622 RF is an ensemble method, where in this case you average results from 500 trees. `randomForestFit$results` returns both RMSE and RSquared, see `?train` for a lot more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `predict`:

```
# Sample data
set.seed(2017);
xx <- runif(100);
yy <- xx * 10 + runif(100);
df <- data.frame(xx, yy);

# Random forest model
library(caret);
randomForestFit <- train(yy ~ ., method = "rf", data = df);

# Predictions
df$pred <- predict(randomForestFit, data.frame(xx = xx));

# Show src data and predictions
require(ggplot2);
gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x = xx, y = yy)) + geom_point();
gg <- gg + geom_point(aes(x = xx, y = pred), col = "red");
gg <- gg + geom_segment(aes(x = xx, xend = xx, y = pred, yend = yy));
gg <- gg + labs(title = "RF predictions in red");

# Fit results
randomForestFit$results;
#  mtry      RMSE  Rsquared       MAE     RMSESD  RsquaredSD      MAESD
#1    2 0.3782246 0.9832667 0.3169568 0.03332236 0.003349397 0.03072483
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. when i do `randomForestFit$finalModel$mse` and `randomForestFit$finalModel$rsq` why do i get 500 values? i was expecting to see 100 values...does `randomForestFit$results` return `rsquared` and `rmse` for the training data?  `rsquared` and `rmse` are very low. Are they correct?

Comment: RF is an ensemble method where in this case you average results from 500 trees. See `randomForestFit$finalModel`. Assessing the quality of your model is really an entirely different question, there exist *many* different ways to achieve that.

Comment: i get now why there are 500 rsq and mse values...but why rsquare is so bad?

Comment: @user2543622 In my example, the Rsquared is 0.98, so not bad at all. Your number will be different because we're using different RNG seeds when generating test data, but your value should be similar nevertheless. BTW, this is an excellent example of why you should use a fixed seed `set.seed(...)` when sharing code here on SO, to ensure reproducibility of results.

Comment: i  used `set.seed(1)` before my code and then I ran the code that i have given above in my question. `randomForestFit$results` gave me `Rsquared` of `0.01191166`...how did you check your models rsquare?

Comment: It's a bit pointless to use `set.seed`, and then to not include which RNG seed you used in your code example. Either way, I've edited my answer to include a fixed seed and show the model quality results. I'm not sure how you got such a low `Rsquared` value. But the quality of your model fit is very adequate.

Comment: i agree with you...i was just confused why i was getting so low rsquare and i added `set.seed` so that i could share code with you. I was getting bad rsquare because `yy=xx*10+runif(100)` was before `xx=runif(100)`..appreciate your help

Comment: @user2543622 Great, glad to help!